# Logstash Error: JMX connector server communication error

Tags: containers, logstash, jmx

I'm runing logstash as a container, everytime when I type a command logtash or logtash-plugin, it always show error
Error: JMX connector server communication error: service:jmx:rmi://b098d1310e6f:18080

So I have no way to install plugin for logstash. pls advise me how to fix this issue.
thanks.